# Is there any way to fix the position of a UISearchBar + UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a ViewController nested inside a PageViewController which is also nested inside a NavigationViewController.

The thing is I have put a UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController item on the center of my ViewController and for some reason, when I click on the search bar and the keyboard appears, the UISearchBar goes up to where the NavigationBar is. Also, when I click outside the UISearchBar, it dissapears with a fading effect.

Could someone explain to me what is going on? How can I fix the position of the UISearchBar so that it does not go up?

I tried a similar UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController on an empty project with a single ViewController and the UISearchBar does not dissapear and does not move up. From this I believe that for some reason the UISearchBar moves up in the presence of a NavigationBar, which acts like a magnet.

Comment: I tried in separate projects with and without embedding in navigation controller, but it did not disappear or move up. _Although, I suggest you to place the searchBar always at the top, or else it would get hidden under the new `searchResultsTableView` that pops up on searching._

Comment: @GoGreen Did you try it using a UISearchDisplayController? 
It is weird, because I have a project with a UISearchBar and a UISearchDisplayController inside a ViewController and the search bar does not go up or anything strange when clicked on and dismissed. Then, I embedded the ViewController in a NavigationController and the issue I explained in my question happens (the search bar goes to the top of the view).

Placing the searchbar on the top of the view would likely be my last option.

Comment: @EngineerWho did you ever figure this out. I have similar issue.

Comment: @slik Unfortunately there does not seem to exist a fine way to achieve this. I guess I will have to extend the TextField class to make it use the SearchBar methods.

Comment: @EngineerWho Yes, I ended up ditching UISearchDisplayController. Thanks for the reply.